# Error in `fct_reorder()`: ! `.f` must be a factor or character vector, not a data frame - trying to reorder a bar plot

Tags: r, bar-chart, forcats

I have a summary table with means for 4 variables from a dataset with 940 rows:

```
activity_means <- activity_daily_clean %>%
  summarize(sedentary = mean(sedentary_minutes),
            lightly_active = mean(lightly_active_minutes),
            fairly_active = mean(fairly_active_minutes),
            very_active = mean(very_active_minutes))
```

I want to plot them into a simple bar plot, but the levels of activity intensity (sedentary - lightly active - fairly active - very active) appear disorganized:

```
act_means_df <- data.frame(
  activity_intensity=c("sedentary", "lightly active", "fairly active", "very active"),
  intens_means=c(991.2106, 192.8128, 13.56489, 21.16489)
)

ggplot(act_means_df)+
  geom_col(aes(x=activity_intensity, y=intens_means))
```

[image: disorganized bar plot]

I tried following the [guide in the R Graph Gallery](https://r-graph-gallery.com/267-reorder-a-variable-in-ggplot2.html) to reorder a bar plot following the values from the second variable:

```
act_means_df <- data.frame(
  activity_intensity=c("sedentary", "lightly active", "fairly active", "very active"),
  intens_means=c(991.2106, 192.8128, 13.56489, 21.16489)
) %>%
  mutate(f_act_int = factor(activity_intensity))

act_means_df %>%
  fct_reorder(f_act_int, intens_means) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=f_act_int, y=intens_means))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw()
```

But the following error appears when I run the last chunk:
Error in `fct_reorder()`:
! `.f` must be a factor or character vector, not a data frame

I confirmed whether f_act_int is a factor with: `str(act_means_df)`:
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
$ activity_intensity: chr  "sedentary" "lightly active" "fairly active" "very active"
$ intens_means      : num  991.2 192.8 13.6 21.2
$ f_act_int         : Factor w/ 4 levels "fairly active",..: 3 2 1 4

But when I try to inspect the object by itself  with `class(f_act_int)`, the error message says "object 'f_act_int' not found".

Does anybody know what I am missing?

Comment: you must add the name of the DF  `class(act_means__df$f_act_int)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `fct_reorder` within `dplyr::mutate()`.

This isn't the only way to solve this issue, but the gist of your error is that you're passing your whole data frame, when it expects a factor or character vector. Instead, try this:

```r
act_means_df %>%
  mutate(fa_act_in = fct_reorder(f_act_int, intens_means)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=f_act_int, y=intens_means))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw()
```

There is no object in your global environment called `f_act_in`; When you call `fct_reorder()` within `mutate()`, R looks inside your data frame for a column with that name, upon which performs the operation in order to return an updated data frame. This updated data frame is then passed to `ggplot()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, nesting fct_reorder inside mutate() should fix it, but now it gives the error:
Problem while computing `f_act_int = fct_reorder(f_act_int, intens_means)`.
Caused by error in `check_factor()`:
! object 'f_act_int' not found

Comment: You still need to create `f_act_int` via your initial call to mutate. You could combine both calls into something like `mutate(act_means_df, fa_act_in = ordered(activity_intensity) |> fct_reorder(intens_means))`